# How to see DHCP assignments in Draytek Vigor 2920 router

Tags: dhcp, draytek

Web interface looks chaotic for me. Where can I see a list of computers, which had received IP addresses by DHCP?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about that specific model, but the 2130 has a page under "Diagnostics" called "DHCP Table" that shows the current DHCP leases.

"Bind IP" under "LAN" just shows the ARP table, which isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Where can I see a list of computers, which had received IP addresses by DHCP?

"Diagnostics" > "DHCP Table"

> The facility provides information on IP address assignments. This
> information is helpful in diagnosing network problems, such as IP
> address conflicts, etc.
>
> Click Diagnostics and click DHCP Table to open the web page.
>
> [image: ![enter image description here]

Source [Draytek Vigor-2920 Manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/draytek/vigor-2920/manual-91.pdf) (pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Under "LAN" tab (right) click (I think) "Bind IP"... I've installed a couple of Vigors and I'm 99.999% sure it's under that tab...